# Is it safe to use space as delimiter to concatenate words where language of the content is unknown

Tags: nlp, language-detection

I have to perform NLP (language detection in particular) on a input. The input has multiple fields:

> {   field1: "",   field2: ""   ... }

I want to merge all the fields and perform NLP. I am not sure however, is it safe to use "SPACE" as the delimiter to concatenate the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short. YES. If you sanitaze your input so you are only left with letters and other characters from different languages then space sounds like a logic answer.